# error in ACAccount.h in Simulator-iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, acaccount

I'm trying to build and test an app with the xcode simulator, but during the building I get errors in ACAccount.h, ACAccountType.h, etc.
The "strange thing" (at least for me as i'm completely new in using xcode) is that if I click on the .h files with errors they do not appear under the project code but under

```
Simulator - iOS 7.1-> Frameworks -> Accounts -> ACAccount.h
```

which is unmodifiable.

Examples of the errors are:

line:

```
 @class ACAccountType,ACAccount Credential;    --> Illegal interface qualifier

 ACCOUNTS_CLASS_AVAILABLE(NA, 5_0)
 @interface ACAccount : NSObject       -->Objective-C declarations may only appear in global scope
```

If the .h are predefined files.. How can I solve these errors?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If That's a copy-paste from the header file then it indicates that the file has been corrupted in some way - the first line that you have an error on should read: `@class ACAccountType, ACAccountCredential;` - i.e. a forward class declaration.

Comment: yes it's a copy paste error.. the ";" is in the line.. Question corrected

Comment: Show some of the file that is performing the `#import` of `ACAccount.h` - it reads like you're putting the `#import` inside an `@interface foo ()` `@end` block. Import statements are best placed at the top of the file outside any `@` sections.

Comment: please write this as answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally when you encounter items like the 'illegal interface qualifier' in system provided headers it indicates that you've placed the `#import` statement within an `@interface` block, like:

```
@interface foo ()

#import <Accounts/ACAccount.h>

@end
```

This generates errors about the content in the file being imported (e.g. your `illegal interface qualifier` error), while the actual issue is that putting `#import` statements within an `@interface` block is invalid.

You should put `#import` statements together at the top of the file, outside of any `@interface` or `@implementation` blocks.

If you put it into the `@implementation` section, the error becomes:

> > error: Objective-C declarations may only appear in global scope